# Clarification on the definition of $C_b^\infty$

Tags: definition

In Pierre-Louis Lions' famous work *Axioms and fundamental equations of image processing*, he defines $C_b^\infty$ on Page 9 as

> ...on $C_b^\infty$, i.e., the space of bounded functions having bounded derivatives at any order.

And on the next page, he defines $Q$, a subset of $C_{b}^{\infty}$

> $$
> Q=\left\{f \text { in } C_{b}^{\infty}, \forall n \geq 0,\left\|D^{\alpha} f\right\|_{\infty} \leq C_{n} \text { for all }|\alpha|=n\right\}
> $$
> and $C_n$ is an arbitrary increasing sequence of nonnegative constants.

What is the difference between $Q$ and $C_{b}^{\infty}$? For me they should be identical. Am I missing something?

Comment: $$C^\infty_b=\{ f\in C^\infty\,:\,\exists \{C_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N},\forall n\ge 0,\forall \lvert \alpha\rvert=n,\lVert D^\alpha f\rVert_\infty\le C_n\}$$ whereas, given some $C:=\{C_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ (such that yada yada yada), $$Q=Q_C=\{f\in C_b^\infty\,:\, \forall n\ge 0,\forall \lvert \alpha\rvert=n,\lVert D^\alpha f\rVert_\infty\le C_n\}$$

Comment: Sounds pretty reasonable. Anyone has other idea?